# Python logger not working for django with apache

Tags: python, django, apache, logging, django-1.6

I have no idea why this is not working. Im using linode to host my ubuntu server with apache hosting my django.

in my settings.py file I have this to define my logger

```
 import logging

 LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
    'standard': {
            'format' : '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s'
    },
},

'handlers': {
    'default': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
        'filename': '/logs/django.log',
        'maxBytes': 1024*1024*5,
        'formatter' : 'standard',
        'backupCount': 5,
    },
},
'loggers': {
    '': {
        'handlers': ['default'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
},
```

}

then I use it in my view like this

```
   import logging
   logr = logging.getLogger(__name__)

   def login(request):
      logr.debug("THIS BETTER WORK >:O")
      c = {}
      c.update(csrf(request))
      return render_to_response('accounts/login.html', c)
```

I'm not getting any error messages or any output just nothing its not writing to file or anything.

What am I doing wrong? I created the log file put it in the right spot and gave it full permissions. I'm getting pretty desperate at this point. I just want any way to log something so I can start debugging my website.

Comment: Can u get the other error messages over apache? Maybe your apache configuration is wrong.

Comment: what is file permission for `/logs/django.log` ??

Comment: Yea i get errors in appche log. 

File permission is 777

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck in the same issue once. What I found was a bit confusing to me, but it worked. The issue was with parameter

```
disable_existing_loggers: True,
```

Using this param to true, means you want to disable all the loggers and override it with existing django logger which you have defined. But, it does not do so automatically. You also need to redefine those loggers in the settings.py file and also their parents.

In my case, I did not have any such requirement. So rather than going from the pain of redefining all the logger I just changed the parameter and set it to false. And it worked.

```
disable_existing_loggers: False,
```

I hope this solves your issue. Permission checks can also be performed.

Additionaly, you can user [Sentry](http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/django.html#django-1-3-or-newer) to trace what is wrong with your code.

Comment: It didn't work :/

Where does the file name start at? Is it dirOfSettingsFile/logs/django.log ? or is it basedir/logs/django.log

Comment: I think the problem is with your configuration. You have used:

    'filename': '/logs/django.log',

Now what Django will look for here is "logs" directory under "/", and then will create a file inside the directory. So, in case of permission issues or directory not present, file will not be created and you will observe nothing.

To fix this, either create a "logs" directory inside your "/" directory. Please note this will fail, in case you run it in Windows machine.

Comment: A better approach will be to use "filename': 'logs/django.log' param and create logs directory under the same directory where settings.py reside.

Answer (score 1):

I am couple of years late but anyways i faced similar issue and below is my comment

```
'filename': '/logs/django.log',
```

to

```
'filename': '/fillpath/logs/django.log',
or
BASE_DIR = 'django project path'
'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs/django.log'),
```

Also in the views or wherever you want to log things

Below one works with django runserver but not with apache httpd

```
import logging
logme = logging.getLogger('__name__')
```

Make below change and it will work for apache/httpd

```
import logging
logme = logging.getLogger('seekers')
```